# what does :: mean ? why do i have .java at the end?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to send a simple explicit intent to start a new activity , I previously used to code in Java & the syntax was pretty simple , I switched to kotlin recently & I have no idea what the :: or the .java extension at the end is doing ?

```
fun Run(view: View) {
    
    // what the heck is :: ? why do i have a .java at the end ?
    val intent:Intent= Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references

Answer (score 2):

`::` creates a [member reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) or a [class reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references)

Here what it does is getting the reference to `MainActivity2`. In Java you'd do this with `MainActivity2.class`.

In Kotlin, `MainActivity::class` returns a value of type [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/), which is different from Java class reference. But the `Intent` function expects a Java class reference, so you use the `.java` property on the reference to get the Java class reference